# Flutter : open a chat room for 2 users based on condition

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

hello I am building a chat app with firebase , and I already know how to make the chat room and make users chat with each other .

in my app i have a Cupertino picker which have some values , what iam looking for is

1 - if 2 users have selected the same value a chat room document will be created and both of them will chat with each other , what are the possible solutions for that ? .

2 - notifications based on topic that are dynamic should be by using cloud functions and typescript with `onCreate` method right ?

Answer (score 0):

1 - you could do something like creating an object like this

```
users_waiting_for_connection -> user_id, selected_value, creation_time, ...
```

So when a user pick a value you check for elements in the list for the same selected_value.. if found you create the room and delete the object from the list, if not found you create the element in the list

2 - yup, you can find any info in the documentation

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/overview/

Comment: can you provide a code example for what you are saying , because i dont think that this is what iam looking for